# How to write compilation rules for a bootstrapping compiler

Tags: shake-build-system

I want to write build rules for a self-hosted compiler. Taking the example of [GHC](http://haskell.org/ghc/), the GHC compiler is written in Haskell, and compiles Haskell. I want to first compile the source using an existing copy of the GHC compiler (phase1), then compile the compiler using the phase1 compiler (phase2) then compile the compiler using the phase2 compiler. How can I encode that in Shake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is similar to writing [fixed-point build rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622169/how-to-write-fixed-point-build-rules-in-shake-e-g-latex). Some asumptions:

- I assume each source file is compiled to one object file with no additional dependencies (the complexities of include/import files are orthogonal)
- I assume the objects and results from phase1 end up in the directory `phase1` etc.

You can define:

```
want ["phase3/ghc" <.> exe]

let getPhase x = read $ drop (length "phase") $ takeDirectory1 x :: Int

"//*.o" *> \out ->
    let src = dropDirectory1 out -<.> "hs"
    let phase = getPhase out
    let compiler = if p == 1 then "ghc" else "phase" ++ show (p-1) </> "ghc" <.> exe
    need $ src : [compiler | p /= 1]
    cmd [compiler] "-c" [src] "-o" out

("//ghc" <.> exe) *> \out ->
    let os = map (takeDirectory1 out </>) ["Main.o","Module2.o",...]
    need os
    cmd "link -o" [out] os
```